# Android Notifications and battery life

Tags: android

Before a couple of years I wanted to implement notifications service in application.
I wanted to make the notification alive as foreground. That the user can't stop.
But I read an article that said this type of notifications is bad for battery life.

Now I need to implement again. But I was looking over the internet about this issue and I cant find it. Does it solved or still exists ??

Comment: the user can always stop the service by killing it

Comment: @tyczj I know. But when the application is reopened it can be triggered again

Answer (score 1):

There's some good discussion on this [Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Does-having-push-notifications-turned-on-or-off-affect-the-battery-life-on-my-iPhone-in-a-significant-way), but the general consensus is that the effect of having such a notification should cause negligible battery life loss, so it would seem the problems does not exist today.

Comment: This thread is for IOS, but I hope Google solved this if it was really exists.

Comment: Im using an app since 5 days and it also has notification that keeps showing on the notifications bar. And Ive checked the battery life I even cant see the application listed on the top battery usage. Its almost only 1%

Comment: Whoops, pasted the wrong link, sorry! I'll edit it. And look into something like the GSAM Battery Monitor to keep a close watch.